# Weird behavior of git sparse-checkout

Tags: git, macos, sparse-checkout

I have a remote named `git@github.com:MyOrg/my-repo.git`

There are several folders within its root directory.

I only want to fetch **ONE** of them, named `datadog`.

I am running the following commands

```
$ g clone --no-checkout --depth=1 git@github.com:MyOrg/my-repo.git
Cloning into 'my-repo'
...
...
...

$ cd my-repo

$ git sparse-checkout init

$ git sparse-checkout set datadog

$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 pantelis  wheel    96B Oct  8 12:39 .
drwxrwxrwt  37 root      wheel   1.2K Oct  8 12:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x  13 pantelis  wheel   416B Oct  8 12:41 .git

$ g sparse-checkout list
datadog

$ g checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   5 pantelis  wheel   160B Oct  8 12:41 .
drwxrwxrwt  37 root      wheel   1.2K Oct  8 12:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x  14 pantelis  wheel   448B Oct  8 12:41 .git
drwxr-xr-x   9 pantelis  wheel   288B Oct  8 12:41 datadog
drwxr-xr-x   4 pantelis  wheel   128B Oct  8 12:41 terragrunt
```

Where did that `terragrunt` directory come from? I know it is in my repo's root by why was it added in my `sparse-checkout`?

**update**: If I use the `--cone` option when initialising `sparse-checkout` it will indeed add only `datadog` folder but also *ALL* other root files (`README.md`, `LICENSE.md` etc) which isn't the desired behaviour either.

Comment: Can you create a sample repository so that others can test ?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this on my linux box using [this](https://github.com/pkaramol/test-repo) public repo I just created and it is not reproducible. On my mac I have `git` 2.33.0 and on my `linux` I have 2.25.1; I will try to install the same `git` version on my mac

Comment: Note that sparse checkout is evolving (it's been undergoing some rather massive changes recently). The version difference in this case would explain everything.

Comment: I tested getting expected result (only datadog) on `git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)`. Working as well on Linux `git version 2.25.1`